# Why is my hamburger menu not letting me have it my way?

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, hamburger-menu

Is this the suicide prevention hotline?  I sure hope so, because I've about had it with this cheeseburger.  Please, save a life and help me out.

I've searched through the questions and the most similar issues to mine are still not answered after many moons.

[The website I am speaking of...](https://thomasskinks.com/) has an exceptionally erratic hamburguesa menu.

Magento ver. 2.1.8

It pretty much never works on Chrome, regardless of the page you're on.  It sometimes works on Firefox.  Even on the same page, sometimes it works, sometimes not.

I'm assuming it has to do with script(s) not loading, but I'm too much of an amateur on Magento to get this narrowed down enough.  I've already spent more time than I'd like to admit.  I've also noticed that the search function doesn't show up when the hamburger doesn't work, but shows up when the hamburger works.  So it seems as though they are looking for the same script.

Sometimes when the hamburger works, the "Menu" and "Account" seem to be on top of one another.  I'm not sure if that could also be related.  Like I said, it is erratic as can be.

If I were smart, I would have checked on it to see what I did to make it stop working correctly, but I never claimed to be brilliant, and any changes that could have affected the menu was done far too long ago.

I'm not necessarily asking for an exact solution, but I know there are thousands of people on here that could probably take 3 minutes to inspect the code and instantly say, "well, there's your problem."  Or if someone could just point me in the right direction, I'd be tickled pink.

You can roast me for not asking a detailed enough question, but I truly believe this is about as thorough as I can be, given the circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your site in Chrome, and press Cntrl + Shift + i (Command + option + i on Mac) to open the developer console.  You'll immediately see about 16 errors, most of which are `403 - Forbidden` errors. The biggest glaring issue is that `pub/static/version1518325605/frontend/thomasskinks/theme-thomasskinks/en_US/requirejs/require.js` fails to load. This is a core script, and without it, most of the Magento scripting fails to work properly.

Something I noticed is that your paths have `/pub/` in them. Magento 2 is supposed to have the document root of Apache or Nginx set to `/pub/`.  Here's an example of setting the document root in Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.tld;
    root /path/to/magento2/pub;

    # Now include /path/to/magento2/nginx.conf
    include /path/to/magento2/nginx.conf;
}
```

The `nginx.conf` file included above is really just a copy of the `nginx.conf.sample` file with the correct "upstream" PHP server filled in.

Why it works sometimes, and doesn't work other times is odd. Some things to check:

1. Have you run the static-content deployment command on the server? `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
2. Are the files in `pub/static` actually readable by the user your webserver (Apache or Nginx) is running as?

For the docroot issue, please see: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/basics/basics_docroot.html

For the file system permissions, please see: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html

Comment: I'll check that all out and get back to you.  Thanks a million for the reply.

Comment: Ended up being permissions that I had to have my hosting company change.  That, and somehow some files seemed to be corrupted.  An update through the Magento admin cleared it all up.  Good to go now.  Thanks again @Brett